# How is this parallel for not processing all elements?

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, parallel.for

I've created this normal for loop:

```
    public static Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,bool>> AnalyzeFiles(IEnumerable<string> files, IEnumerable<string> dependencies)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>> filesAnalyzed = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            filesAnalyzed[item] = AnalyzeFile(item, dependencies);
        }
        return filesAnalyzed;
    }
```

The loop just checks if each file that is in the variable "files" has all the dependencies specified in the variable "dependencies".

the "files" variable should only have unique elements because it is used as the key for the result, a dictionary, but I check this before calling the method.

The for loop works correctly and all elements are processed in single thread, so I wanted to increase the performance by changing to a parallel for loop, the problem is that not all the elements that come from the "files" variable are being processed in the parallel for (in my test case I get 30 elements instead of 53).

I've tried to increase the timespan, or to remove all the "Monitor.TryEnter" code and use just a lock(filesAnalyzed) but still got the same result

I'm not very familiar with the paraller for, so it might be something in the syntax that I'm using.

```
    public static Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,bool>> AnalyzeFiles(IEnumerable<string> files, IEnumerable<string> dependencies)
    {
        var filesAnalyzed = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();

        Parallel.For<KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>>(
            //start index
            0,
            //end index
            files.Count(),
            // initialization?
            ()=>new KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>(),
            (index, loop, result) =>
            {
                var temp = new KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>(
                               files.ElementAt(index),
                               AnalyzeFile(files.ElementAt(index), dependencies));
                return temp;
            }
            ,
            //finally
            (x) =>
            {
                if (Monitor.TryEnter(filesAnalyzed, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        filesAnalyzed.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Monitor.Exit(filesAnalyzed);
                    }
                }
            }
            );
        return filesAnalyzed;
    }
```

any feedback is appreciated

Comment: If you need to *lock* access inside `Parallel.For`, you are doing it wrong. Besides, the *finalizer* runs on a single task. It doesn't need locking.

Comment: Besides, why are you using `Parallel.For` instead of `Parallel.Foreach`? You end up iterating over the `files` enumerable multiple times, when you could just pass a single `file` value to your method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the feedback, I'm not familiar with the parallel for neither the foreach, I was just trying to create the parallel loop, so I could use for sure the Foreach instead of the For

Comment: the big problem here is that `IEnumerable` has to be evaluated each time you try to access a value. That means, that each time you call 
`Count()` or  `ElementAt`, it will have to be evaluated *again*. You'd have the same problem if you used `for(int i=0;...)`

Comment: Also if  the underlying enumerable for `dependencies` is a complicated linq query (or something similar), you should evaluate it into list locally and send that into AnalyzeFile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your normal loop this way:

```
   Parallel.Foreach(files, item=>
    {
        filesAnalyzed[item] = AnalyzeFile(item, dependencies);
    });
```

You should also use **ConcurrentDictionary** except Dictionary to make all process thread-safe

Comment: Yes, That's why ConcurrentDictionary should be used.

Comment: thanks! I've chosen this as answer because IN MY CASE it was faster than using @Magnus code. It looks like the Parallel.Foreach spawned more threads (12 or 13) than the number of available processing threads ( 8 ), in my case it looks like this was good because I have A LOT of I/O.

Comment: @Robson If you have a lot if IO perhaps you should go async instead. Parallel is for processor intensive code.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the code inside `AnalyzeFile` and `dependencies` is thread safe, how about something like this:

```
var filesAnalyzed = files
    .AsParellel()
    .Select(x => new{Item = x, File = AnalyzeFile(x, dependencies)})
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item, x=> x.File);
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight mixing up different function calls is not a good idea. `ToDictionary` is supposed to do one job - *collect/reduce* the results of the parallel computation into a single result. `Select` performs a projection in parallel. Can you say for *sure* that putting the transformation in `ToDictionary` won't result in serial execution?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if you [check the source of ParallelEnumerable.ToDictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs,4997) you'll see that `ToDictionary` work synchronously on the results, which *is* the expected behaviour

Comment: in theory the code inside AnalyzeFile is thread safe because I don't use anything out of the two parameters, and it's only read methods, but people pointed out that I need to use ConcurrentDictionary instead of the normal Dictionary

Comment: @Robson Not for the case of my answer, the gathering of the thread results is handled internally by PLINQ. But if you use a `Parallel.For` you would need to.

Comment: dependencies is a 'string[]' that I create before calling 'AnalyzeFiles', I'm assuming it is thread safe if I just read and not modify the vector right?

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code a *lot* if you use Parallel LINQ instead :

```
public static Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,bool>> AnalyzeFiles(IEnumerable<string> files, IEnumerable<string> dependencies)
{
    var filesAnalyzed = ( from item in files.AsParallel()
                          let result=AnalyzeFile(item, dependencies)
                          select (Item:item,Result:result)
                        ).ToDictionary( it=>it.Item,it=>it.Result)               
    return filesAnalyzed;
}
```

I used tuple syntax in this case to avoid noise. It also cuts down on allocations.

Using method syntax, the same can be written as :

```
var filesAnalyzed = files.AsParallel()
                         .Select(item=> (item, AnalyzeFile(item, dependencies)))
                         .ToDictionary( it=>it.Item,it=>it.Result)
```

`Dictionary<>` isn't thread-safe for modification. If you wanted to use `Parallel.ForEach` without locking, you'd have to use `ConcurrentDictionary`

```
var filesAnalyzed = ConcurrentDictionary<string,Dictionary<string,bool>>;

Parallel.ForEach(files,file => {
    filesAnalyzed[item] = AnalyzeFile(item, dependencies);
});
```

In this case at least, there is no benefit in using `Parallel` over PLINQ.

Comment: thanks for your time! it looks like Parallel.ForEach was faster than the AsParallel

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what is exactly going wrong without debugging the code. Just looking at it though I would have used a `ConcurrentDictionary` for filesAnalyzed variable instead of a normal `Dictionary and get rid of the Monitor.

I would also check whether same key already exists in the dictionary filesAnalyzed, it could be that you are trying to add a kvp withthe key that is added to the dictionary already.